# Obtener datos de diferentes tipos de un archivo csv y pasarlos a un typedef struct c++

Tags: c++

Estoy empezando en C++.

Estoy intentando hacer un programa (con funciones propias de C++ y no de C) dónde tengo un typedef struct Persona con datos de diferentes tipos, creo un array de 5 personas de tipo Persona, y luego intento rellenar los datos de esas personas con los datos que hay en un archivo csv.

El csv contiene lineas de datos así:

> 1001  pepito  PRJ 23550

Dónde: int id, string nombre, char [] iniciales, int puntos.

No sé cómo hacerlo, mi intento es creando un ostringstream al que le doy una secuencia de entrada de datos que coincide con como le va a entrar una linea de datos con getline.

No sé como substraer cada uno de los datos recogidos para asignarlos a persona[i].id_persona etc.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;
using std::ios;

#include <sstream>
using std::ostringstream;

typedef struct{

    int id_persona;
    string nombre;
    char iniciales[3];
    int puntos;

}Persona;

Persona personas[5];

int main(){

    int id_persona_aux;
    string nombre_aux;
    char iniciales_aux[3];
    int puntos_aux;

    string linea;

    ostringstream registro;

    registro << id_persona_aux << nombre_aux << iniciales_aux << puntos_aux;

    ifstream datos("csvprueba.csv", ios::in);

    while(getline(datos, linea)){

        registro << linea;



    }

    return 0;

}
```

Muchas gracias, estoy empezando, puede que codee o diga tonterías, pero espero que sirva para aportar a la comunidad.

Comment: Los datos de tu archivo ... ¿ están separados **por espacios** ( ` ` ) o **por comas** ( `,` ) ?

Comment: Perdón, estan separados por tabulaciones.

Comment: Si las iniciales son 3 caracteres, necesitas un *char[4]* para guardarlas, ya que siempre hay después de los caracteres visibles en terminador \0. Aunque sería más limpio que, siendo c++, usaras *string* para todo...

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que todas estas variables que terminan en `_aux` podrían ser `std::string`, y hacer algo como esto:

```
while (getline(datos, id_persona_aux, ' '))
{
    getline(datos, nombre_aux, ' ');
    getline(datos, iniciales_aux, ' ');
    getline(datos, puntos_aux);
}
```

El tercer argumento para `getline` es el separador. Yo puse un espacio pero puede ser lo que sea.

Así cuando hayas leído las cuatro partes de cada registro, ya las puedes convertir tú al tipo correcto para meterlas al struct.

Y por cierto, si quieres definir `Persona` como C++ más moderno, podrías hacer esto:

```
using Persona = struct {
   int id_persona;
   string nombre;
   char iniciales[3];
   int puntos;
};
```

Ahora así se hacen los typedefs.

Comment: "*Ahora así se hacen los typedefs*" es falso :) No se hacen `typedefs` para estructuras en [tag:c++] ni ahora, ni nunca :P